# htaccess rewrite to change gif urls

Tags: .htaccess

I hope you can help.
I'm trying to do a htaccess rewrite changing

file.gif to images/file.gif

I'm waded through this site, but can't find it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Mark

Comment: As it stands the question is rather vague, please add more details to it.

Comment: Hi Fmendez. Sorry, I have a number of links which I can't change <img src="1234.gif"> - I need it to look in images/1234.gif

Answer (score 1):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule (?!^images/)^([^.]+\.gif)$ /images/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Provide some details like what URI did you try? And what behavior did you see?